# Updating database with multiple checkbox values received from the loop?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I am trying to update my database with multiple values. Input fields are in a loop, so I need to update multiple checkboxes and textboxes at the same time.

```
$cityID = $_POST["cityID"];
$cityStatus = $_POST["cityStatus"];
$cityOrder = $_POST["cityOrder"];  

$updateCities = $db->execute("UPDATE cities SET city_status=?, city_order=? WHERE city_ID=$cityID", array($city_status, $cityOrder));

foreach($cities as $row) :
?>

<input type="checkbox" name="cityStatus[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="cityOrder[]" value="<?php echo $row->city_order ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cityID" value="<?php echo $row->city_ID; ?>">
```

Comment: Whats the question?Any errors?

Comment: why are you injecting `$cityID` directly in your query, when you are using placeholders for the others?

Comment: Input fields are in a loop, so I am trying to update multiple checkboxes at the same time.

Comment: if this is in a loop, then you have multiple `name="cityID"`. Should it be `name="cityID[]"`

Comment: I've also tried it but I get "Array to string conversion" error

Comment: You need to give all your inputs the same key, as only checked checkboxes are posted on form submit, so in order to know which one is checked to access the other fields, they all need to be the same, ie. `name="cityStatus[$row->city_ID]"`/`name="cityOrder[]"`/`name="cityID[$row->city_ID]"`. Then you can loop over each checkbox using the key - `foreach($_POST['cityStatus'] as $key => $value) { $_POST['cityStatus'][$key]; $_POST['cityOrder'][$key]; $_POST['cityID'][$key];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understood is
1. you have array of 3 fields (cityid, cityorder, city status)
2. you are submitting all these values from the form
3. you want update cityorder and citystatus depends on cityid

The solutions is pretty simple

```
$i=0;
foreach($_REQUEST['cityOrder']) as $cityorder){

$cityID = $_POST["cityID"][$i];
$cityStatus = isset($_POST["cityStatus"][$i])?$_POST["cityStatus"][$i]:0;
$cityOrder = $_POST["cityOrder"][$i];  

$updateCities = $db->execute("UPDATE cities SET city_status=?, city_order=? WHERE city_ID=$cityID", array($city_status, $cityOrder));

$i++;
}
```